# List all tags in SVN repo

Tags: linux, centos, svn

If I run  `svnlook tree -N /path` I get a list of the top level folders in the SVN repo like this:

```
/
 tags/
 trunk/
```

But what I need to see is a list of the current tags. I know I can turn off `-N` but this then lists every single file and it is impossible to see the list of directories in `/tags/`

I have tried `svn ls "^/tags"` when I am in the repo directory and that gives the following error:

```
svn: E155007: Resolving '^/': no repository root found in the target arguments or in the current directory
```

If I do `svn ls /path` it is says `/path is not a working copy directory`.

I have checked the manual and can't see any way to list the tags and not the whole file structure.

Answer (score 0):

`svnlook tree -N /path` works if you then leave a space and then add the path to the tags folder, so `svnlook tree -N /path /tags`

But not `svnlook tree -N /path/tags`

Answer (score 0):

You may run `svn list` like this:

`svn list https://demo-server.visualsvn.com/tortoisesvn/tags`

And the output is going to be as follows:

```
version-1.10.1/
version-1.10.2/
version-1.10.3/
version-1.10.4/
[snip]
```

If you need to list tags locally on the server, then you may use the `file://` URL as in this example:

`svn list file:///path/to/repository/tags`